# what is the difference between the two pieces of code that calculate the sum of log probabilities?

Tags: r

I am a biologist. I am trying to learn R scripting. The first code is from a datacamp course to calculate the sum of log probabilities. I wrote the second, which is obviously wrong.  I know the output is different. I just want to understand why we needed to add the "[i]"

```
#code1
n <- 100
total <- 0
x <- runif(n)
for(i in 1:n)
total <- total + log(x[i])
total
```

```
#code2
n <- 100
total <- 0
x <- runif(n)
for(i in 1:n)
total <- total + log(x)
total
```

A better way to solve this is

```
log_sum <- sum(log(x))
```

I just want to understand the difference between the 2 codes.

Comment: Most R functions including `+` and `log` are vectorised.  This page should help you understand what this means and why your code does what it does.  https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/09-vectorization/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `x` is a vector of 100 separate values, not just one value.

`x[i]` is a way of denoting "the `i`th element in x".  `x[1]` is the first element, `x[2]` the second etc.

This section of code:

```
for(i in 1:n)
  total <- total + log(x[i])
```

says "starting from one, and counting up by one each iteration until I we reach the number defined by `n`, do the following, with the current count being represented by `i`:
Take the value of `total`, add to it the `log` of `i`th element of the object `x`, and store that as the new value of `total`.

In other words, when you run that it goes through the loop 100 times and each iteration it takes the `log` of one of the values of x and adds it to the running total.

In some programming languages, this would be the main or most obvious way to do this.  In R, there is a concept called "vectorisation" which is quite important.

In those programming languages, if you ran `log(x)` and `x` contains 100 values you may receive an error message - the `log()` function is expecting a single value, it doesn't know what to do with 100 of them.  Thanks to vectorisation, when you pass R's `log()` function a vector of 100 values it happily returns a vector containing 100 logs - the equivalent of running `log()` on each of those values in turn and assembling them into a new vector.

Let's look at your version:

```
for(i in 1:n)
  total <- total + log(x)
```

R treats this as though it says "starting from one, and counting up by one each iteration until I we reach the number defined by `n`, do the following, with the current count being represented by `i`:
Take the value of `total`, add to it the `log` of **every single element** of the object `x`, and store that as the new value of `total`.

You can see that this loop will run 100 times, and each time add ALL the logs of values of x to the running total - we will end up with a result 100 times bigger than expected.

This is also the reason this works:

```
log_sum <- sum(log(x))
```

This says "take the `log` of all the elements of `x` in turn, `sum` them, and assign the result to the variable `log_sum`

I hope that helps.